# interpolate function - matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Do you know about [similar function to this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html) where points are narrays (matrix)?

I try to convert function from matlab:

```
Ex=interp3(X,Y,Z,squeeze(Emat(1,:,:,:)),x(1),x(2),x(3), 'linear', 0);
```

to python. Tried:

```
Ex=interpn((X,Y,Z), np.squeeze(Emat[1,:,:,:]), np.array(x))
```

but X, Y, Z should be tuple of ndarray of float, while in matlab is has shape 12 12 12.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something along these lines?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def linear_approx(x,xf1,xf2):
    (x1,f1) = xf1
    (x2,f2) = xf2
    return f1*(x-x2)/(x1-x2) + f2*(x-x1)/(x2-x1)

x1, f1 = 0.0, 3.0
x2, f2 = 2.0, -2.0

plt.plot(x1,f1,"ro")
plt.plot(x2,f2,"ro")

myx = np.linspace(-1,4,200)
plt.plot(myx,linear_approx(myx,(x1,f1),(x2,f2)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I am looking for function that have input points reprezented by 3 matrix. I edited by question. I am sorry it wasn't clear.